# Period of least significant bits of linear congruential random number generator

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, random

On a practice exam for a course on stochastic simulations I encountered the following question:

> Show that the least significant $n$ bits must repeat with a period $2^n$
>   for a congruential random generator with a period $2^m$ where $m > n$.

I couldn't find an answer on how to do this anywhere. How can I shows this? Is it just that the $n$ bits can only generate $2^n$ numbers?

Comment: What is the definition of congruential random number generator?  $x_n = ax_{n-1} + b \mod c$ or $x_n = ax_{n-1} \mod c$? and what are the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Comment: That is not given but I assume $x_n = a x_{n−1}$mod$c$, with $a=2^n$ and $c=2^m$.

Comment: Try your generator with, say, $x_0 = 1023$, $n=5$, $m = 32$.  What are the values of $x_1$, $x_2, \ldots$?  Hint: computation by hand is easy, especially if you represent the $x_i$ as $32$-bit words.

Answer (score 1):

In Chapter 3 of D. E. Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming,* vol. 2, (1st edition), it is shown that the low-order $n$ bits repeat with a period of $2^n$ 
*or less* for *any* choice of the multiplier $a$. If you want to prove that 
the period is *exactly* $2^n$, then you may need to place restrictions on 
$a$.  You may also need to place restrictions on the modulus $c$ because
Knuth also says that if the modulus $c$ is $2^m$ (as in your comment), 
then the low-order bits are not quite as random as is possible with 
other choices of $c$.

Comment: In short: using the least significant bits for generating "new" random numbers isn't that good an idea. :)